# set the maximum processor state to 99%

Tags: power-management, lenovo, intel, cpu

I have a Lenovo y50-70 with the screen flickering issue and I fixed it in Windows by set the max processor state to 99% in Advanced Power Management [Advanced Power Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAYGn.jpg)

is there anyway to do the same in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought the solution sounds a bit odd to me *(if demanded the processor will normally go to 100%)*, but you might want to take a look at `cpu freq` from `Ubuntu Software` center.
  It is a GUI over cpufreq, which can be used to set the CPU frequency profile.